# Effectively remove everything except repeating end characters

Tags: python, strip

What effective way is there to just leave the repeating end characters in a given number? (like reversed strip)(I couldn't find a fast method)

For example

`number='184950273400000'
print((number).strip('0'))`

The outcome is 1849502734

But I was wondering how to instead of striping the 0s, effectively strip everything before the 0s. So the outcome would be 00000.

And in this case `len(number)` would == 5

I was wondering if there was something like reversed strip because I am trying to find the length of repeating end numbers.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate fibonacci zeros? If so, there's a much faster way to calculate the zeros.

Comment: I am trying to find the 0's from a very large factorial but found the method I was using was to slow to properly work. But what method could that be, maybe it could work?

Comment: How about `s[-1] * (len(s) - len(s.strip(s[-1])))`. It's ugly and probably horribly inefficient, but it works. A regex match constructed using `s[-1]` might be cleaner.

Comment: Are they integers or strings as your input? Is it only identifying zeroes or any repeating final digit?

Comment: Input is a string number, only repeating final zero actually, I probably should have stated that.

Comment: "I am trying to find the 0's from a very large factorial" - then computing the factorial at all is a mistake. You only need to compute how many times 5 goes into the result.

Comment: You will likely be given test cases where the actual factorial doesn't even fit in your computer's RAM.

Comment: "I am trying to find the 0's from a very large factorial" -- like mentioned above, computing the factorial will take much longer than stripping the 0s if the factorial is so large as to make your method prohibitively expensive. I would exploit the structure of the factorial, such as computing how many times a 10 goes in the result.

Comment: Jerome, I completely agree. That's what I was also trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reversed` function to efficiently generate the string as a sequence in reverse order, so that you can use `itertools.takewhile` to output only the leading characters that are equal to `'0'` with `'0'`'s equality method, and then join the characters for output:

```
from itertools import takewhile
''.join(takewhile('0'.__eq__, reversed(number)))
```

This avoids iterating through any (potentially very long) part of the string leading to the trailing zeroes.

Comment: This seems like a lot of gymnastics to make this a one liner over a small function: running timeit between this and Daniel Scott's answer (using reverse in place of slicing) gives the simple solution a 2.5x speed advantage over using itertools when using a 2.1M digit number (they are both almost independent of number length, which is what you'd expect). They both are orders of magnitude faster than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the performant option. It only requires scanning the last digits.

```
def count_zeros(number):

    number=str(number)
    i=0
    for digit in reversed(number): #count backwards
        if digit!=number[-1]:
            return i
        else:
            i+=1
```

Comment: You can almost always omit generating your own index in python. `for digit in number[::-1]:` will give you each `digit` in reverse order.

Comment: `digit` is the value you're interested, not an index: `if digit == '0':` I'd also be curious how you're getting `log n` as your complexity.

Comment: Great suggestion TemporalWolf, that's cleaner. My mistake on the logn - I hastily figured he was counting large fib numbers.

Comment: I'd encourage you to test your changes before making them. In it's current form your code doesn't run with multiple errors.

Comment: Appreciate the encouragement. :)

Comment: The last bit of advice I'd give is to replace the slice I told you to use with `reversed(number)`. slicing generates the full list in reverse, `reversed()` will use an iterator and therefore gives a huge speed up on arbitrarily large numbers. With that change, this becomes the fastest answer so far provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re

number='184950273400000'

re.search(r'0+$', number).group(0)
# 00000
```

You can also use the function `takewhile()` with a reversed string:

```
from itertools import takewhile

''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x == '0', number[::-1]))
# 00000
```

Finally you can use the length of the stripped string:

```
number[len(number.rstrip('0')):]
# 00000
```

Comment: Dang! Beat me to it.

Comment: for large numbers this will be inefficient: there is no reason to generate internal matches or scan the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

If wanting to find the number of trailing zeros of a factorial as suggested by the comments, it might not always be possible to compute the factorial to use the other methods suggested. Instead, you only need to compute the factors of 5 that go into the number. This won't be faster than the other methods if a number is already provided, but is much faster than computing the factorial.

```
def count_zero(n):
    return sum([n//5**(i+1) for i in range(int(math.log(n, 5)))])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process it from a string (instead of the math approach), you would probably get the best performance by using only iterators:

```
from itertools import takewhile
countTrailingZeroes = sum( 1 for _ in takewhile(lambda c:c=="0",reversed(number)) )
```